# Is it possible to use tal:conditions in a Javascript file?

Tags: javascript, html, zope

I am working on creating a new context menu that provides more accessibility. The old menu was using the context menu ID's to check conditions with tal in Index.html. My issue now is that I am no longer using action and not using the ID's. The new context menu is creating each menu with a different ID. I tried declaring "var emp_menu_items = [];" in a script tag inside the condition and removing it from the Employee class but I'm still getting error that it is undefined.

I also tried building the new context menu in Index.html but it needs parameters that are  inside of Employee.js. So is there a solution to use the tal:conditions in a JS file?

Index.html

```
<a metal:fill-slot="context_menus" tal:omit-tag="">
    <ul id="employee_context_menu" class="hidden" tal:define="sec_posted python:container.util.checkSecurity(mn_name='Posted')">
      <li tal:condition="python:layout == 'np'"><a href="#assign_pat">Assign Patients</a></li>
      <li tal:condition="python:container.util.checkSecurity(mn_name='File')"><a href="#hr_file">HR File</a></li>
      <li tal:condition="python:sec_posted"><a href="#schedule">Pay Period Schedule</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Close">Close Menu</a></li>
    </ul>
```

This is the old menu in Employee.js class

```
$name.contextMenu({
          menu:      "employee_context_menu",
          leftClick: true
        }, function(action, elem, position) {
          if(action == 'Close') {
            jQuery(".contextMenu").hide();
            return true;
          } else if(action === 'hr_file') {
            $iframe.attr('src', 'Personnel/cgi_utran/cgi_utran?args=-i'+$div.data('obj').id).load(function() {resizeIframe(this)});
          } else if(action === 'assign_pat') {

              $j.PatientAssignment.assign_check = emp.id;
              $name.addClass('highlight');

              var title_str ='Assign Patients to ' + employee_name;
              $j.PatientAssignment.sub_title = ''
              var mheight = $j(window).height()*0.7;
              $j('#beds').dialog('close');
              $j('#beds').css('max-height',mheight).dialog({
                      modal: false,
                      title: title_str,
                      height:'auto',
                      width: 'auto',
                      close: function() { $name.removeClass('highlight'); }
              });

              syncPatientAssignments();
              syncBedAssignments();
              return true;

          } else if(action === 'schedule') {
            $iframe.attr('src', 'ScheduleStaff/cgi_daystaff?szDate='+emp.shiftdate+'&szID='+emp.id+'&args=-t').load(function() {resizeIframe(this)});
          } else if(action === 'assign_work') {
            $iframe.attr('src', 'ScheduleStaff/cgi_daystaff?args=-t OneEmployee -I'+emp.id+' -B'+emp.shiftdate).load(function() {resizeIframe(this)});
          } else { }
          $name.addClass('highlight');
          $j("#modal_window").dialog({
            modal:    true,
            width:    'auto',
            show:     'scale',
            hide:     'scale',
            height:   'auto',
            close:  function() {window.location.reload(); $name.removeClass('highlight'); }
          });
        });
```

My changes to the context menu in Employee.js

```
employeeContextMenu($div, emp, employee_name, count) {
      var emp_menu_items = [];
      var emp_menu = {};
      emp_menu_items.push({
          name: 'Assign Patients', title: 'Assign Patients',
          fn: function(el) {
            $j.PatientAssignment.assign_check = emp.id;
            var title_str ='Assign Patients to ' + employee_name;
            $j.PatientAssignment.sub_title = ''
            var mheight = $j(window).height()*0.7;

            if ($j('#beds').hasClass("ui-dialog-content") && $j( "#beds" ).dialog( "isOpen" )){
            $j('#beds').dialog('close');
              }
            $j('#beds').css('max-height',mheight).dialog({
                    modal: false,
                    title: title_str,
                    height:'auto',
                    width: 'auto',
                    position: [670, 115],
                    focus: function(event,ui) {
                      $j(".ui-icon-closethick").focus();
                    },
                    buttons: {
                      OK: function(){
                        $j(this).dialog("close");
                      }
                    }

            });

            syncPatientAssignments();
            syncBedAssignments();
            }
        });
      emp_menu_items.push({
            name: 'HR File', title: 'HR File',
            fn: function(el){return pop_over_window('Personnel/cgi_utran/cgi_utran?args=-i'+$div.data('obj').id);}});
      emp_menu_items.push({
            name: 'Pay Period Schedule', title: 'Pay Period Schedule',
            fn: function(el){return pop_over_window('ScheduleStaff/cgi_daystaff?szDate='+emp.shiftdate+'&szID='+emp.id+'&args=-t');}});
      emp_menu_items.push({
            name: 'Close Menu', title: '',
            fn: function(el){return false}, });
    
      emp_menu = new ContextMenu('employee_context_menu_'+count, 'Employee Context Menu Options', '.name', emp_menu_items, {container:$div[0]});
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are looking for is to use server-side code inside a javascript "file" (I presume from the tagging of your question that you are working in Zope, so the javascript would be contained in an object in the ZODB).

Create your *Employee.js* as a **DTML Method** or **DTML Document** or **Script (Python)** to this end.

In the DTML objects, instead of tal-conditions, you can use `<dtml-if>my js code<dtml-else>more js code</dtml-if>` and any other DTML construct.

Of course you could also write a Python Script that returns the javascript code.